# Rails edit view. Selected value on select from foreign key

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form_for editing my `Branch` model and the following select populated by all my `StoreType` model.

`<%= f.select :store_type_id, options_from_collection_for_select(StoreType.all, :id, :name), :selected => @branch.store_type_id%>`

The `Branch` model has a foreign key field referencing store types called `store_type_id` and I would like the selected value of the field to be the corresponding Store type. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an option to give to the options helper:

```
<%= f.select :store_type_id, options_from_collection_for_select(StoreType.all, :id, :name, @branch.store_type_id) %>
```

The 4th argument of `options_from_collection_for_select` is the index of the selected value ;-)

**Usage:**

> options_from_collection_for_select(collection, value_method, text_method, selected = nil)

**Documentation:** http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_from_collection_for_select